# How to click a button from Browser with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I would like to click on the "OK" button with the selenium

[Button generated from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bt3c.png)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. In order to get the most out of this site, please take the [tour], and have a read through [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the JavaScript alerts. Selenium has alert class to handle them. Refer below code:

```
#python webdriver code
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://sandbox.dev/alert.html")
alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept() #this line accepts the alert
browser.close()
```

Java Webdriver code to accept alert:

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.Alert; //import this class

    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
```

Comment: in Selenium "Alert" is not a class, it is an Interface with the abstract methods